# Npm "scripts": "start" run express and open url

Tags: node.js, angular, express, npm

I have this entry in `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node bin/www"
  },
```

It runs my Express app when I enter the command `npm start`.

But I also want a browser to open `http://localhost:8081` at the same time.

Something like:

"start": "node bin/www, http://localhost:8081"

So when I type `npm start`, it both runs my Express app and opens the URL.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

As far as I know it's like writing a bash command:

```
// Windows
"start":"start http://localhost:8081 & node bin/www"

// Mac
"start":"open http://localhost:8081 && node bin/www"

// Linux
"start":"xdg-open http://localhost:8081 && node bin/www"
```

Comment: I am no Windows and `"start":"node bin/www & start http://localhost:8081"` wont work

Comment: However if I have errors in the app then it is starting the new browser window with specified url but if there is no errors so no window is shown

Comment: Ok I think I know why, see the updated answer. The `&` in windows will run the second command after the first. When node fails, it finishes that command and then opens the browser. When node doesn't fail, it doesnt finish and the browser window never opens.

Answer (score 24):

For cross-platform support use [open-cli](https://github.com/sindresorhus/open-cli).

Install it:

```
npm install --save-dev open-cli
```

Add it to your scripts:

```
"start": "open-cli http://localhost:8081 && node bin/www"
```

Comment: Great solution. By the way: To escape `&` in the url use `\\&`, i.e. `open-cli https://localhost:8081?var1=foo\\&var2=bar && node bin/www`

Answer (score -1):

You just need to use `start` in the right order!

Incorrect:

```
"start": "npm run dev & start http://localhost:8000",
```

Correct:

```
"start": "start http://localhost:8000 & npm run dev",
```