# How can I get 'ng serve -o' to launch a page other than index.html?

Tags: angular-cli

Our angular app will be embedded in an iframe when in production. In development, we have a file, host.html, which has an iframe whose src is the angular app's index page. We can 'ng serve' and then manually bring up host.html and it works fine.

But, 'ng serve -o' wants to open up the app index file; how do I make it open host.html instead?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So I don't think angular cli supports opening an arbitrary page with the `-o` option, but you could make your own `npm` script that does what you want.

Try opening `package.json` and editing the `scripts` section to update the `start` script like so *(mac version)*:

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",

    // where localhost:4200 is your dev host and port, respectively
    "start": "ng serve && open http://localhost:4200/host.html",

    "build": "ng build",
    ...
  },
```

Depending on what platform you're using, the script would need to be written differently:

```
// Windows
"start":"ng serve & start http://localhost:4200/host.html"

// Mac
"start":"ng serve && open http://localhost:4200/host.html"

// Linux 
"start":"ng serve && xdg-open http://localhost:4200/host.html"
```

Then, instead of using `ng serve` to start your app, use `npm start`.

Reference: used [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35261535/npm-scripts-start-run-express-and-open-url) for the platform specific `open` commands.

Comment: This doesn't work because "ng serve" never finishes, so "& start ..." never executes. At least that is my experience on Windows.

Comment: @rwalker reversing the order might work. i.e. `start http://localhost:4200/host.html & ng serve`. Haven't tried it, but it will probably create a race condition. It should immediately open up a browser window to the given URL and then start the server. If the server process gets far enough along before the browser actually finishes opening, then the page should open and wait for compilation to finish. Otherwise you'll need to manually reload the page after compilation finishes.

Answer (score 0):

Open **package.json** and edit the scripts section to update the start script.

Another way  `ng serve --open --port=any port no`  Example: `ng serve --open --port=4216`

Comment: As the OP pointed out, the `--open` flag is explicitly not what they are looking for as it opens the app's root URL.